# psmouse driver inverse mouse

Tags: c++, linux, driver

I just wanna have fun with the mouse driver under Ubuntu Linux. I have got the psmouse-base.c and I can compile it and load it to a kernel as well. The only thing which I want to do is to inverse the mouse. I have found this function which receives the data from the mouse

```
psmouse_interrupt(struct serio *serio,unsigned char data, unsigned int flags)
```

where the received data is stored in the unsigned char data. I figured it out that 6 data represents every possible mouse state so it receives 6 data and after 6 again but I cannot figure it out what does these data stand for. If somebody could tell me the answer or tell me where to find a documentation which describes it I would be happy.

I think I have found something. Since I use touch pad I keep receiving 6 byte. I found the description of the data here: www.synaptics.com/sites/default/files/511-000024-01a.pdf. It can be found at the 2nd and the 3rd page. According to this documentation the direction of the movement can be found in the 4th byte's 4th and 5th bits. But the following code does nothing:

```
if (psmouse->pktcnt == 3)
{
    data  |= 1 << 4;
    data  |= 1 << 5;
}
```

I would assume that I could only move my mouse only in one direction in the x and the y axes.

I have found out that the driver which is responsible for my touch pad is elentech.c.

```
x1 = ((packet[1] & 0x0f) << 8) | packet[2]; 
y1 = etd->y_max - (((packet[4] & 0x0f) << 8) | packet[5]);
```

And these lines calculates the movement. I could reverse my touch pad in the x axes but it was just a luck. I have no idea why it works. The following line does it:

```
psmouse->packet[1] *=-1;
psmouse->packet[2] *=-1;
```

However I would assume that the next lines do the same thing that the previous two but they don't:

```
psmouse->packet[1] ^= 0x80;
psmouse->packet[2] ^= 0x80;
```

And I wasnt able to inverse the mouse in the y axes. Any idea?

Comment: If you want to change the direction of the mouse movement, you should modify the FIRST byte, not the third, however.

Comment: that is for the standard ps/2 mouse which sends 3 byte. But for the touch pad it is not true. And that is the 4th byte because it starts from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably better off modifying the code that handles the packet, [`psmouse_process_byte`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse-base.c#L131), rather than the interrupt handler itself.

It reports the X&Y movements [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+%2a/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse-base.c#L206), and it shouldn't be very hard to make it move the other way around.

Basically, all you need to do is reverse the XNG/YNG bits (packet[0] bits 4 & 5 respectively).

Here's one page that describes the packet format:
http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2mouse/
Another here:
http://wiki.osdev.org/Mouse_Input

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try it tomorrow but it will probably work. Thank you

Comment: I found the psmouse_process_byte and the lines where it reports the movement. I tried to modify it but nothing happened. At the and I commented out both lines and the mouse still worked well so what?

Comment: Maybe your mouse is not a PS/2 mouse, but, say, a USB mouse?

Comment: Yes sorry for not mentioning that I am using a touch pad :S. But if I remove psmouse module (rmmod psmouse) my touchpad stops working so I am sure that this driver is responsible for my touch pad. I have updated my question.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I'm not really an expert on the way that mice work in Linux - I know enough to be dangerous, but not enough to be an expert by any measure. Have you looked at the code for the synaptics driver - for example here: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/drivers/input/mouse/synaptics.c#L1142
(Your driver may be slightly different, but I expect it's largely the same). Drivers in Linux often "chain together", so removing a basic driver can lead to removing some parts that the driver depends on.

Comment: I have checked the loaded modules (lsmod) and I couldn't find any synaptics module loaded.

Comment: On my machine, I can't find a mouse-driver at all - but my mouse works. Must be built in, I expect.

Comment: The second-to-last link is broken (the whole www.computer-engineering.org site is broken (the domain expired)). Some alternatives are (essentially the ***same content by the same author***, but slightly different titles and modification dates): *[The PS/2 Mouse/Keyboard Protocol](https://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/PS2%20Keyboard.pdf)* (2003), *[The PS/2 Keyboard Interface](http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/datasheets/PS2%20Keyboard%20Protocol.htm)* (2003), and *[The AT-PS/2 Keyboard Interface](https://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Interface/atkeyboard.pdf)* (2001).